# Fail to start Appium server in 60 seconds

Tags: appium, katalon-studio

I am testing an android application on katalon studion. When i am running a sample mobile project on katalon studio i am getting this error[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBof1.png).

I have checked that whether appium server is running or not. So, by typing the command appium on cmd my appium server is running. [desired capabilities settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1CS4.png) 
[Remote connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5mLI.png)